# Is cylinder target tracking possible with ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I want to place my 3d models onto a cylinder object, and when I rotate the object, the model should rotate along with it. Is this possible with Apple ARKit?

I tried Image Tracking Configuration, using a long image wrapped around my object, but it didn't seem to work (ARKit did not recognize the image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically it's possible (it's not easy), but a tracking of cylindrical objects (like bottles or vases) is not ARKit's greatest strength. You'll have to additionally implement CoreImage and Vision techniques. Pay attention to the fact that only five types of anchors in ARKit conform to [ARTrackable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/artrackable?language=objc) protocol. These are:

- ARAppClipCodeAnchor
- ARBodyAnchor
- ARFaceAnchor
- ARGeoAnchor
- ARImageAnchor

As you can see, there's no ARObjectAnchor in the list. And you have to consider that only objects with fine-perceptible textures are acceptable.

Use [PTC Vuforia](https://developer.vuforia.com) to get a considerably better results with [cylinder targets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wz4Qi6Jfo4k).

Comment: Thank you. I'll use Vuforia for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/content_anchors/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects

Also, as alternative you can also use the Vuforia SDK for this:
https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried object tracking but the problem is that my target is very small, like a ring or so and ARKit does not detect it. Have you succeeded in tracking small object before?

Comment: Not yet but tracking is totally depends on image Dataset to identify object then trigger an event, please make sure your target object/image have proper dataset.

Comment: Yes I have proper dataset, but ARKit object detection does not seem to work well with small object. I'm leaning on Vuforia option. Thank you.